Using a zsh script to add a chunk of text to a file on MacOS
I want to use sed in a script to modify the content of an existing file. I have a line like this...
sed -i '' 's/${scripts}/${newScripts}/' "$packpath"

... which does not do what I thought it would do on my Mac. I would appreciate any help you can give to correct this line.

On my Mac, I have created a script at ~/.zshrc which contains the lines:
if [ -f ~/.bash_aliases ]; then
  . ~/.bash_aliases
fi

I have a script at  ~/.bash_aliases which contains a number of aliases and functions to handle common tasks.
I often create small React projects that I want to deploy to GitHub, using the gh-pages Node module. One step in this process is adding two lines to a file called package.json.
For simplicity, let's say that the package.json file looks like this, before adding any lines.
{
  "name": "react-project",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "vite",
    "build": "vite build"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0"
  }
}

After, it should look like this:
{
  "name": "react-project",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "vite",
    "build": "vite build",
    "predeploy": "npm run build",
    "deploy" : "gh-pages -d dist"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0"
  }
}


The function that I have added to my .bash_aliases currently looks like this:
ghdeploy() {
  package="package.json"
  packpath="$PWD/$package"
  packtext=`cat $packpath`
  
  deploy_it=",\\n    \"predeploy\": \"npm run build\",\\n    \"deploy\" : \"gh-pages -d dist\"\n  "

  setopt local_options BASH_REMATCH
  regex='"scripts":[^\}]+'

  if [[ "$packtext" =~ "$regex"  ]]; then
    scripts=$BASH_REMATCH[1] ## includes final \n\s\s

    if [[ "$scripts" =~ ("deploy": "\w+") ]]; then
      echo "package.json already contains deploy script"

    else
      chunk=${scripts:0:-3} ## remove final \n\s\s
      newScripts="$chunk$deploy_it"
      echo "newScripts: $newScripts"
      sed -i '' 's/${scripts}/${newScripts}/' "$packpath"
    fi

  else
    echo "scripts not found"
  fi
}

The line echo "newScripts... prints out the change that I want to make, but the line sed -i '' ... does not apply those changes to my file.
What is it that I have failed to understand?

Shell variables are not expanded within single quotes. Try v="Hello" followed by echo "$v" then echo '$v'

It's better to use jq instead of sed.

@MarkSetchell My variables already contain " characters, so using "s/${scripts}/${newScripts}/" (which I think is what you are suggesting) fails. If I use \s/${scripts}/${newScripts}/`, I get the error ghdeploy:32: no such file or directory: ...`

" within your variables are not the same as "s around your variables (the former is just another literal char while the latter is an instruction to the shell to expand the variable but not do globbing, word splitting, and filename expansion on it) and of course wrapping it in `s fails as that's asking the shell to execute the contents of your variable as it it were a command. See https://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes for what quotes mean and when/where to use them.

"s/${scripts}/${newScripts}/" is the right thing to do as far as quoting in the sed command goes, if it doesn't do what you want then you have an additional problem. And don't use sed -i before you have a working sed script as that can mangle your input file, just use sed without -i and look at the output on your terminal until it does what you want and THEN add the -i.

At a first glance: Your function is bash code, but you run it from zsh. Without analyzing the details, I can already see that you are using BASH_REMATCH in it. I suggest that you rewrite the content of .bash_aliases so that it contains zsh code. Of course, I would also rename the file afterwards...

It's very unlikely that sed is the right tool for this since you probably want a literal string replacement but sed doesn't understand literal strings, see is-it-possible-to-escape-regex-metacharacters-reliably-with-sed. This will do what you want using any awk:
$ cat tst.sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

ghdeploy() {
  local package packpath tmp

  tmp=$(mktemp) || exit
  trap 'rm -f "$tmp"; exit' EXIT

  package='package.json'
  packpath="$PWD/$package"

  awk '
    /"scripts": \{/ {
        inScripts = 1
    }
    inScripts {
        if ( $1 ~ /^}/ ) {
            if ( scripts ~ /"deploy"/ ) {
                printf "%s already contains deploy script\n", FILENAME  | "cat>&2"
            }
            else {
                deploy_it = ",\n    \"predeploy\": \"npm run build\",\n    \"deploy\" : \"gh-pages -d dist\""
                scripts = scripts deploy_it
            }
            $0 = scripts ORS $0
            inScripts = 0
        }
        else {
            scripts = (scripts == "" ? "" : scripts ORS) $0
            next
        }
    }
    { print }
    END {
        if ( inScripts == "" ) {
            print "scripts not found" | "cat>&2"
        }
    }
  ' "$packpath"
  #' "$packpath" > "$tmp" && mv -- "$tmp" "$packpath"
}

ghdeploy


$ ./tst.sh
{
  "name": "react-project",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "vite",
    "build": "vite build",
    "predeploy": "npm run build",
    "deploy" : "gh-pages -d dist"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0"
  }
}

Just replace ' "$packpath" with ' "$packpath" > "$tmp" && mv -- "$tmp" "$packpath" when you're done testing and happy with the output.
